# check if a date exists within a grouped row and if it does then change column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, pdo

I have a database query that groups payments due into monthly values.

The problem I am facing now is that I can not see each individual payments to be able to make sure all are paid.

dp within the column is Date Paid.

If the date within the column is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 then no payment has been made.

Here is the query:

```
$monthlyQuery = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT SUM(net) AS net
     , MONTH(dd) AS month
     , YEAR(dd) AS year
     , dp 
  FROM sin WHERE cpo=:cpo 
   AND dd >= :dd1 
   AND dd <= :dd2 
 GROUP 
    BY month 
 ORDER 
    BY dd ASC
 ");
$monthlyQuery->execute(array(':cpo' => $fetch['cpo'], ':dd1' => $janDate, ':dd2' => $decDate));
$monthlyQueryNum = $monthlyQuery->rowCount();
```

is there a way to check each dp column before the row is grouped and if at any point the date is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 then make all dates for that group 0000-00-00 00:00:00

I was thinking of doing a CASE WHEN THEN but the logic doesn't seem to work for me.

Thanks

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't given us data to test this against, I've written the following without being able to test it. It should be close to what you want:

```
SELECT
    SUM(s.net) AS net
    ,MONTH(s.dd) AS month
    ,YEAR(s.dd) AS year
    ,COALESCE(missing.inner_dp,s.dp) AS dp 
FROM
    sin s
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        YEAR(s2.dd) AS inner_year
        ,MONTH(s2.dd) AS inner_month
        ,cpo AS inner_cpo
        ,dp AS inner_dp
    FROM
        sin s2
    WHERE
        s2.dp = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        AND s2.dd >= :dd1 
        AND s2.dd <= :dd2 
    GROUP BY
        inner_year, inner_month, inner_cpo, inner_dp
    ) AS missing ON
        YEAR(s.dd) = missing.inner_year
        AND MONTH(s.dd) = missing.inner_month
        AND s.cpo = missing.inner_cpo
WHERE
    s.cpo=:cpo 
    AND s.dd >= :dd1 
    AND s.dd <= :dd2 
GROUP BY
    year, month, dp
ORDER BY
    year, month, dp
```

I'm not a fan of MySQL allowing "implicit" `GROUP BY` expressions, and I've made them explicit. You'll notice I also changed the `ORDER BY` as the one you had looked problematic to me.

Comment: Did this answer help, @Robert? Keen to know either way, and happy to interact further if we're not quite there yet.

Comment: Hi @steve-lovell no it just gave back the same results as I was getting in the first place.

I decided to just go with 1 simple sql query and simply use php multi-functional arrays and some simple functions to sort them.

Was a lot harder and to be honest, it is most likely no where near as efficient as a sql query but it was the only way I could get round this.

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hmm, I feel there is something we're missing. Can you add sample data and expected output to your question?